# Converting innertext in Simple HTML Dom parser data from string to numeric

Tags: php

I am using simple_html_dom.php for HTMl Parsing.
Following is a part of code from which I am taking the innertext value.

```
<div class="precurrentvalue">
<span class="current-price" data-role="currentvalue">1,228.55</span>
</div>

$nse_price = $html->find("div[class='precurrentvalue']");
$col_price=$nse_price[0]->innertext;
echo "Col price1  " . $col_price;
echo "<br>";

$col_price = str_replace( ',', '', $col_price );
echo "Col price2  " . $col_price;
echo "<br>";
$col_price = floatval($col_price);
echo "Col price3  " . $col_price;
echo "<br>";
```

The output I get is as follows
Col price1 1,228.55 
Col price2 1228.55 
Col price3 0

I want a numeric output with 2 decimal point as I need to do the calculation based on this value.

What swould be the solution.

Comment: Code works fine https://3v4l.org/JniBZ.

Comment: If you put a static value $col_price= "2312.22", it works for me also. But I Take it from $nse_price[0]->innertext it does not work

Comment: Your Code should work fine....

Answer (score 1):

use `number_format` with all numbers:

```
$col_price = number_format(floatval($col_price), 2);
```